# methods of clearing float's effects

Tags: css, css-float

There're dozens of ways to clear float in order to make sure the containing block containing all his descendents including floating children.

1. using markup:`<div style="clear:both;"></div>`
2. Creating a new block formatting context:

   - is floated
   - is absolutely positioned
   - has a display property value of one of more unusual properties(table-cell,etc.)
   - overflow

My Question is : is there any other method?

Many thanks for helping!

Comment: Related http://stackoverflow.com/questions/490184/what-is-the-best-way-to-clear-the-css-style-float

Comment: thank you, but i have given these methodes what the link said. what i want to know is the other method.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Some methods you *didn't cover* in your question:

- `display: inline-block` - I wouldn't really count that as `"an unusual display value"`, although it's not usually used to clear floats because of it's side effects (such as shrink-wrapping): http://jsfiddle.net/CLXbc/
- The `clearfix` class - this is a common technique - http://jsfiddle.net/CLXbc/1/

  ```
  /* The Magnificent Clearfix: Updated to prevent margin-collapsing on child elements.
     j.mp/bestclearfix */
  .clearfix:before, .clearfix:after { content: "\0020"; display: block; height: 0; overflow: hidden; }
  .clearfix:after { clear: both; }
  /* Fix clearfix: blueprintcss.lighthouseapp.com/projects/15318/tickets/5-extra-margin-padding-bottom-of-page */
  .clearfix { zoom: 1; }
  ```

By far the two most common methods are `overflow: hidden` and `clearfix`.

Going through your other options, here's why they aren't optimal:

- `"using markup:<div style="clear:both;"></div>"` - this is not semantic. Splattering clearing `div`s throughout your HTML is a poor choice.
- `"is floated"` - this works, but you don't usually want the shrink-wrapping.
- `"is absolutely positioned"` - you don't usually want your element to be absolutely positioned.
- `"has a display property value of one of more unusual properties(table-cell,etc.)"` - `display: table-cell` doesn't work in IE7.. and yet again, you don't want the side effects.

I use `overflow: hidden` in most cases. Sometimes I can't use that,  [for example here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5565668/in-2011-is-there-any-need-for-clearfix/5566093#5566093). In those cases, I usually fallback to `clearfix`.

Comment: thank you very much, clearfix class is what i really want to know.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the floating element's parent element to `overflow:hidden;` or `overflow:auto;`.

http://www.quirksmode.org/blog/archives/2005/03/clearing_floats.html

Comment: Thank you, but i have list this method.Any others?

Answer (score 0):

Here's a great read about Floats. Might even give some more insight to long time web developers as well.

http://css-tricks.com/all-about-floats/