# HTML: Div is not effected by image size

Tags: html, css

I have set up a div however the image inside of it exceeds its limits due to `float:left`. Anything possible to fix this?

Here is my code:

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
<div style='width:600px;min-height:50px;border:1px solid black;padding:5px;'>
<img src='pic.jpg' style='border:1px solid #C0C0C0;padding:5px;float:left;height:150px;width:150px;'>
<div>
<p>There are a lot of things </p>
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Clear the float: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6328080/methods-of-clearing-floats-effects

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `overflow:hidden` to parent div

Answer (score 1):

```
<html>
  <head></head>
  <body>
    <div style='width:600px;min-height:50px;border:1px solid black;padding:5px;'>
      <img src='pic.jpg' style='border:1px solid #C0C0C0;padding:5px;float:left;height:150px;width:150px;'>
      <div>
        <p>There are a lot of things </p>
      </div>
      <br style="clear:both;"/>            <!-- the addition -->
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

OK, I am not entirely sure what you are asking, So if this is a wrong answer I apologize in advance, but change:

```
    <img src='pic.jpg' style='border:1px solid C0C0C0;padding:5px;float:left;height:150px;width:150px;'>
```

To:

```
    <img src='pic.jpg' style='border:1px solid #C0C0C0;margin:5px;float:left;height:150px;width:150px;'>
```

Padding will usually expand the width of the parent container, so try margin.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the containing box to expand to fit the image, clear the float.

Few examples of clearing a float: http://jsfiddle.net/MJK4u/1/

More advanced techniques (recommended) for clearing floated elements: [methods of clearing float's effects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6328080/methods-of-clearing-floats-effects)

If you want to hide the overflow, use `overflow-hidden`. If you want the overflow to scroll, `overflow-scroll`.

Answer (score 0):

Hi you can do with two thing as like u

There are two solution of this problem .

1. think you can define your parent overflow hidden because this is collapse margin problem

as lik this

**css**

```
.parent{
    width:600px;
    min-height:50px;
    border:solid 1px black;
    overflow:hidden;
}
img{
    display:inline-block;
    border:solid 1px #c0c0c0;
    padding:5px;
    height:150px;
    width:150px;
    margin:10px;
}

.child{
    display: inline-block;
     vertical-align: top;
}
```

**HMTL** 
    ​

```
<div class="parent">
<img src='pic.jpg' alt="sample img">
<div class="child">
<p>There are a lot of things </p>
</div>
</div>​
```

Live demo [click here](http://jsfiddle.net/rohitazad/awEDY/1/) http://jsfiddle.net/rohitazad/awEDY/1/

***or***

1. is you can define display inline-block of yout img tag and child div as like this

**css**

```
.parent{
    width:600px;
    min-height:50px;
    border:solid 1px black;
    overflow:hidden;
}
img{
    float:left;
    border:solid 1px #c0c0c0;
    padding:5px;
    height:150px;
    width:150px;
    margin:10px;
}

.child{

}
​
```

**HMTL**

```
<div class="parent">
<img src='pic.jpg' alt="sample img">
<div class="child">
<p>There are a lot of things </p>
</div>
</div>​
```

Live [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rohitazad/awEDY/3/) http://jsfiddle.net/rohitazad/awEDY/3/