# Can't align picture and text beneath each other

Tags: html, css, image

I've been trying to do a ridiculously basic task but can't get it through.
I cannot figure how to make the second image be right below the first one. This is frustrating!!

fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/dvir0776/v9v512tm/

```
<div class="comment"><img src="d.jpg" style="width:13%; margin-right: 12px; float:left;">
    <div style="text-align:left; font-size:8pt;">
    <h5 style="margin-bottom:0;">Chris Fanelli</h5>
    comment comment comment comment comment comment comment comment comment comment!</div>
</div>

<div class="comment"><img src="d.jpg" style="width:13%; margin-right: 12px; float:left;">
    <div style="text-align:left; font-size:8pt;">
    <h5 style="margin-bottom:0;">Chris Fanelli</h5>
    comment comment comment comment comment comment comment comment comment comment!</div>
</div>
```

Any tweak to fix it will be great.

Comment: Clearing the floats is the way to go, but how about we clean up your markup, and separate the CSS [like in this example](http://jsfiddle.net/2k9k5jgg/2/)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Line boxes wraps floated elements. You should [clear the `float`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/490184/what-is-the-best-way-to-clear-the-css-style-float) at the end of the container, the `.comment`.

Either by the [traditional way](http://jsfiddle.net/hashem/v9v512tm/1/):

```
<div class="comment">
    <img src="d.jpg" style="width:13%; margin-right: 12px; float:left;" />
    <!-- ... -->
    <div class="clearfix"></div>
</div>
```

```css
.clearfix { clear: both; }
```

Or by [something newer](http://jsfiddle.net/hashem/v9v512tm/3/):

```css
.comment:after {
    content: "";
    display: block;
    clear:both;
}
```

Comment: Comments are going to stack on top of each other, so why not just `.comment { clear: left; }`

Comment: @misterManSam Then what will happen to the rest of document flow? http://jsfiddle.net/hashem/v9v512tm/4/

Comment: Well, it's not [really a problem to clear a float one more time](http://jsfiddle.net/v9v512tm/6/) and comments are often at the bottom of the document, leaving maybe just a footer to clear. I would say it's a viable option.

Comment: @misterManSam Yes only if you are aware of the layout structure which is not specified by the OP. It depends on the layout. I'd go with solutions which stand by their own.

Comment: Of course, though it can't hurt to have it as an option with a side note about clearing the following elements after `.comment`. It is a valid method after all.

Comment: fantastic! You just made a 20yo a little wiser :)

Answer (score 2):

Those answers should work, but [here](http://jsfiddle.net/2x4nyme5/) is an alternative. It uses `display: table-row;`. I adding `padding-top: 10px;` just for aesthetics. The container may not be necessary.

**CSS**

```
.container {
    width: Auto;
}
.comment {
    display: table-row;
    padding-top: 10px;
}
.comment img {
    display: table-row;
    padding-top: 10px;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="comment">
        <img src="d.jpg" style="width:13%; margin-right: 12px; float:left;">
        <div style="text-align:left; font-size:8pt;">
             <h5 style="margin-bottom:0;">Chris Fanelli</h5>
comment comment comment comment comment comment comment comment comment comment!</div>
    </div>
    <div class="comment">
        <img src="d.jpg" style="width:13%; margin-right: 12px; float:left;">
        <div style="text-align:left; font-size:8pt;">
             <h5 style="margin-bottom:0;">Chris Fanelli</h5>
comment comment comment comment comment comment comment comment comment comment!</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

All you have to do is add `clearfix` class to the `comment` div.

```
.clearfix:after {
 visibility: hidden;
 display: block;
 font-size: 0;
 content: " ";
 clear: both;
 height: 0;
```

}

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/v9v512tm/2/)

Answer (score 0):

Add a "`clear:left`" style to the 2nd div

```
<div class="comment"><img src="d.jpg" style="width:13%; margin-right: 12px; float:left;">
         <div style="text-align:left; font-size:8pt;">
         <h5 style="margin-bottom:0;">Chris Fanelli</h5>
         comment comment comment comment comment comment comment comment comment comment!</div>
         </div>

<div class="comment" style="clear:left"><img src="d.jpg" style="width:13%; margin-right: 12px; float:left;">
         <div style="text-align:left; font-size:8pt;">
         <h5 style="margin-bottom:0;">Chris Fanelli</h5>
         comment comment comment comment comment comment comment comment comment comment!</div>
         </div>
```