# Images showing up outside of border

Tags: html, css

I currently have a border like this:
[image: current]
<sub>(source: [gyazo.com](http://gyazo.com/03e2f00fbe3125ba2d69a9136e6839d8.png))</sub>

But I want the flow of the body to go from left to right instead of top to bottom.

When using `float: left;` on a div that controls these, I get this:
[image: broken]
<sub>(source: [gyazo.com](http://gyazo.com/922df1f6586dd3ee7cd49d89fa1f6634.png))</sub>

The images are now completely out of the border.
This is what the current code looks like for the body:

```
<div class="courses">
                <figure>
                    <img src="http://atlanta.eat24hours.com/files/cuisines/v4/chinese.jpg" alt="Asian" height="300px" width="300px" />
                    <figcaption>Bok choi</figcaption>
                </figure>
        </div>
        <div class="courses">
        <figure>
                    <img src="http://atlanta.eat24hours.com/files/cuisines/v4/chinese.jpg" alt="Asian" height="300px" width="300px" />
                    <figcaption>Bok choi</figcaption>
                </figure>
            </div>
```

And of course a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Ljmyfkbc/)
Also, if someone could give me a hint on how to still have the text stay on the right side of the image even when the page is resized too small. If you notice in the fiddle the text will move to the bottom once page becomes too small.

Comment: what error is in fiddle

Comment: Relevant question - [What is the best way to clear the CSS style “float”?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/490184/2930477)

Comment: can you give me your css so i will try it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This issue is arising because you haven't properly cleared your `float: left` - floating an element takes it outside the document flow.  You need to clear the *containing* element (so if you floated .courses, you would need to set the clear on its parent element).

There are three ways to do this:

1. The "hacky" way - set `overflow: hidden;` on the parent .wrapper
2. Set the parent .wrapper to `display: inline-block;`
3. Properly clear the float by adding a pseudo-element to the parent .wrapper:

`.wrapper:after {
    content: "";
    display: table;
    clear: both;
}`

Comment: Would those all be good to use, or is one of those ways better then the others?

Answer (score 1):

add `overflow: hidden;` to class `.wrapper`

working demo http://jsfiddle.net/Ljmyfkbc/2/

Answer (score 1):

Try using below CSS. I think might work for you, as someelse has mentioned it erlier, but I have brief knowledge about php, javascript, I'm only new to stackoverflow.

```
.wrapper:after {
    content: "";
    display: table;
    clear: both;
}
```

No matter there are so many other ways to do that, but it is not better to write complete codes as it doesn't meets the stack overflow policy.

Answer (score 0):

you can use `overflow:hidden` to the class `.wrapper`, else you can use `display:inline-block` to the class`.courses` instead using `float:left`

Answer (score 0):

When you float all elements inside an element, that element will collapse.

Try adding `overflow:hidden;` to your wrapper. It is a common solution to this problem.

Another solution is the following:

```
.wrapper:after {
    content:"";
    display:table;
    clear:both;
}
```

This allows the wrapper's :after pseudo element to clear the wrapper, without having to worry about the potential issues that might arise from using overflow:hidden;

Answer (score 0):

I think this will help you, You need to make reside all your images inside one division instead of giving each images new division also you can do this by changing css for your class.
Like:

```
<div class="courses">
                <figure>
                    <img src="http://atlanta.eat24hours.com/files/cuisines/v4/chinese.jpg" alt="Asian" height="300px" width="300px" />
                    <figcaption>Bok choi</figcaption>
                </figure>
        <figure>
                    <img src="http://atlanta.eat24hours.com/files/cuisines/v4/chinese.jpg" alt="Asian" height="300px" width="300px" />
                    <figcaption>Bok choi</figcaption>
                </figure>
            </div>
```

css:

```
.courses{
any style you want for figcaption and figure.

}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this.,

```
.wrapper{
    background-color: white;
    width: 85%;
    display:inline-block;/*added*/
    border: 2px solid black;
    text-align: center;
}
.courses{
    float:left;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> add css

```
.wrapper{
    background-color: white;
    width: 85%;
    border: 2px solid black;
    text-align: center;
    overflow: hidden;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

> html

```
<div class="wrapper">
        <header>
            <h1>Yoko's kitchen</h1>
            <nav>
                <ul>
                    <li>classes</li>
                    <li>catering</li>
                    <li>about</li>
                    <li>contact</li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
        </header>

        <div class="courses">
                <figure>
                    <img src="http://atlanta.eat24hours.com/files/cuisines/v4/chinese.jpg" alt="Asian" height="300px" width="300px" />
                    <figcaption>Bok choi</figcaption>
                </figure>
        </div>
        <div class="courses">
        <figure>
                    <img src="http://atlanta.eat24hours.com/files/cuisines/v4/chinese.jpg" alt="Asian" height="300px" width="300px" />
                    <figcaption>Bok choi</figcaption>
                </figure>
            </div>

    </div>
```