# Lineup items in a multiple column layout

Tags: html, css, multiple-columns

I am constructing a structure with 3 columns in the layout. And I got 2 issues unresolved:

1. I want to insert a table in the middle column. However, when I do that, the table misplaces at the bottom of the column.
2. The third column also misplaces in the same way as table.

I am wondering why, and any solution to that to put the table up back in place at the top of the column.

```html
<div style="width=100%;">

    <div style="float: left; width: 25%; padding: 5px; height: 100%; background: #F2F2F2">
        <h1>The first column</h1>
    </div>  

    <div style="float: left; width: 50%; padding: 5px">
        <h1>The second column</h1>
        <p>A paragraph in place</p>
        <table>             
            <tr>
                <th>Category</th>
                <th>Title</th>
                <th></th>
            </tr>
        </table>

    <div style="float: right; width: 25%; padding: 5px; height: 100%; background: #EFF7FF">
        <h1>The third column</h1>
    </div> 

</div>
```

Comment: You don't close the second `<div>` after the `<table>`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CSS Flexboxes are easily the coolest thing ever for layout like this.  In addition to removing the floats ( a disgusting way to make columns, no offense) I also had to end the 2nd div before the 3rd one started.  That is possibly your only issue, but like I said, floating things left and right to make columns is pretty gross compared to flex.

```html
<div style="display: flex">

    <div style="padding: 5px; height: 100%; background: #F2F2F2">
        <h1>The first column</h1>
    </div>  

    <div style=" width: 50%; padding: 5px">
        <h1>The second column</h1>
        <p>A paragraph in place</p>
        <table>             
            <tr>
                <th>Category</th>
                <th>Title</th>
                <th></th>
            </tr>
        </table>
      </div>
    <div style="width: 25%; padding: 5px; height: 100%; background: #EFF7FF">
        <h1>The third column</h1>
    </div> 
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, did not notice the style flex, which is really useful!

Answer (score 2):

Two issues there: (1) You forgot to close the `<div>` that is containing the `<table>`. (2) Add `box-sizing: border-box;` so that `padding` will be part of the width, makes all the 3 columns together of 100% width.

Also, don't forget to clear the floats, e.g. set `overflow: hidden;` on the container, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12871710/483779) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/490184/483779) to learn more.

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<div style="width: 100%; overflow: hidden;">

    <div style="float: left; width: 25%; padding: 5px; height: 100%; background: #F2F2F2;">
        <h1>The first column</h1>
    </div>  

    <div style="float: left; width: 50%; padding: 5px;">
        <h1>The second column</h1>
        <p>A paragraph in place</p>
        <table>             
            <tr>
                <th>Category</th>
                <th>Title</th>
                <th></th>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div> <!-- added here -->
    
    <div style="float: right; width: 25%; padding: 5px; height: 100%; background: #EFF7FF;">
        <h1>The third column</h1>
    </div> 
    
</div>
```